# Solving PDE $u_{tt} = u_{xx} + u(x,t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given inhomogeneous wave equation. $0 < x < l$ and $t > 0$
$$u_{tt} = u_{xx} + u(x,t)$$
$$u_{x}(0,t) = u_{x}(l,t) = 0, $$
$$u(x,0) = \cos\frac{\pi}{l}x$$
$$u_t(x,0) = 1$$
I was trying to solve this by using separation of variables method, but something went wrong.
 Now I don't know how to proceed. Here's steps of what was done.
Let's find $U(x,t)$ as product of 2 functions $X(x)T(t)$. By plugging into equation we get.
$$X(x)T''(t) = T(t)X''(x) + X(x)T(t)$$
Dividing both sides by $X(x)T(t)$
$$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)} - 1 = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = - \lambda^2$$
Constructing Sturm–Liouville problem for $X(x)$
$$X''(x) + \lambda^2 X(x) = 0$$
$$X'(0) = X'(l) = 0$$
Here we have 3 cases
1. $\lambda < 0$ we get exponents as solution, and with given boundary conditions, only trivial solution exists.
2. $\lambda = 0$ we get $X_0(x) \equiv 1$ as an eigenfunction.
3. $\lambda > 0$ we get $X(x) = c_1 \cos \lambda x + c_2 \sin \lambda x$, and with given boundary conditions, we find countable eigenvalues $\lambda = \lambda_k = \frac{\pi k}{l}, k = 1,2,\dots$
So eigenfunctions for this case will be $X_k(x) = \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x$ for $k = 1,2,\dots$

We can merge 2 and 3 cases with just  $X_k(x) = \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x, k = 0,1,2\dots$

**Now I guess something went wrong starting from here.**

Constructing $T''(t) + ((\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1)T(t) = 0$
Solving this we get $T_k(t) = a_k \cos(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t) + b_k \sin(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t)$.

So our solution will be $$u(x,t) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left( a_k \cos(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t) + b_k \sin(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t) \right) \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x$$
And
$$u_t(x,t) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1} \left( -  a_k \sin(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t) + b_k \cos(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}t) \right) \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x$$
Applying initial conditions.
$$u(x,0) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k  \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x =  \cos\frac{\pi}{l}x$$
Here only $a_1 = 1$, and $a_k = 0, k \neq 1$
$$u_t(x,0) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty b_k \sqrt{(\frac{\pi k}{l})^2 - 1}  \cos \frac{\pi k}{l} x =  1$$
From here, I've got all $b_k = 0$, which was strange for me.
And final solution was something like this.
$$U(x,t) = \cos(\sqrt{(\frac{\pi }{l})^2 - 1}t) \cos \frac{\pi }{l} x $$
This solution obviously doesn't satisfy equation and second initial condition.
I think I'm missing some key understanding here, could you please point out what did went wrong?
 Thank you for your time.

Comment: your only mistake is writing the $t$ so it looks like it's inside the square root sign.

 Define $$a^2\equiv (\frac \pi l )^2-1$$ 

your result is $$U(x,t)=\cos(at)\cos(\frac \pi l  x)$$ which satisfies all conditions.

Comment: @WW1 Your solution doesn't satisfy $u_{t}(x, 0) = 1$. A solution that does satisfy your conditions is $$u = \frac{1}{a} \sin(at) + \cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{l} \right)$$ where $a$ is some eigenvalue that you'll need to find. In order to find this, you'll need to use your orthogonality conditions to find the form of $b_{k}$. Also, note that your sums should be starting at $k = 1$ and not $k = 0$ for the sine terms.

Comment: @Mattos you're right, I thought it was $$u_t(x,0)=0$$